# SQL запрос по двум столбцам

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица `tb_products`. Надо воспроизвести поиск по двум столбцам: `title` и `description`.

То есть:

`SELECT * FROM tb_products WHERE title LIKE '%квартиры%' OR description LIKE '%квартиры%'`

Мне нужно построить запрос так, чтобы сначала вывелись товары в которых это слово есть в `title`, а потом если этого слова в `title` нету, то в `description`

Спасибо за отклик!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tb_products WHERE title LIKE '%квартиры%' OR description LIKE '%квартиры%'
ORDER BY case when title LIKE '%квартиры%' then 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 4):

> Мне нужно построить запрос так, чтобы сначала вывелись товары в
>   которых это слово есть в title, а потом если этого слова в title нету,
>   то в description

Если решение в лоб, то двумя запросами через `UNION`.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_products WHERE title LIKE '%квартиры%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM tb_products WHERE description LIKE '%квартиры%'
```

Comment: Так могут быть дубликаты, во втором селекте надо убедиться, что строка не попала в первый селект.

Comment: @AivanF.насколько я знаю, простой `UNION` берёт только уникальные записи.

Comment: @Streletz "Квартиры" я привел как пример. Вместо него можно например взять "продается путевка"

Comment: То есть это запрос напрямую связан со строкой поиска

Comment: Если условие отбора Вы берёте со строки поиска тогда понятно...

Comment: Только, если нет номального индекса для поиска, ИМХО, без костылей не обойтись.

Comment: При использовании UNION, порядок строк в результате не гарантируется https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html